# PHP: Connecting PDO to SQL Server

Tags: php, pdo

*I know that there is some discussion on PHP & SQL Server, but most of this is a few years old, and predates PHP; not much mentions PDO either.*

I have a client who wants to access their SQL Server database from their web server. The Web Server is Apache running on Ubuntu Linux, while the SQL Server is running on a separate Windows box.

Most of what I have been able to find is dated, especially since PHP 7 came out.

What do I need to install to get PHP & PDO connecting to to a remote SQL Server?

Comment: PHP's manual point's out to this SQL Server driver : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: Also in the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php